# Why we get an empty map when clear values of it in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map.

```
Map<UUID, List<UUID>> parentsMap
```

When I trying to clear values:

```
parentsMap.values().clear()
```

It clears my map completely. I can do only like this:

```
parentsMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.clear())
```

I know that when we editing the .keySet() of the map, we changing the origin map.
But why when we editing the values() it have influence on the keys??

Comment: @AxelH The question is, however, about `Map.values().clear()`, not `Map.clear()`.

Comment: Indeed @lexicore, missed the `values` call... [`Map.values`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) "_Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa._"

Comment: Do you want to `clear()` each of the value-lists`? Something like `parentsMap.values().forEach(Collection::clear)`?

Comment: FYI: I have down-voted for the lack of effort. The answer is directly found in the javadoc of the method. I don't believe you took the time to open it or you would have found the answer directly.

Answer (score 7):

That's what the Javadoc says:

> **java.util.Map.values()**
>
> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so **changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa**. If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the** Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and **clear operations**. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Just like editing `keySet()` modified the backing `Map`, so does editing `values()`.

Since you want to apply a `clear` operation on each individual `List<UUID>` value of the `Map`, you must iterate over all the values and call `clear()` on each of them separately, as you did in your `parentsMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.clear())` call. You can also do `parentsMap.values().forEach(List::clear)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do map.replaceAll((k, v) -> null); :)

But anyway if you look at values() javadoc

> Collection values()
>
> Returns a Collection view of the values
> contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes
> to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa. If the map
> is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress
> (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of
> the iteration are undefined. **The collection supports element removal,
> which removes the corresponding mapping from the map**, via the
> Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear
> operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parentsMap.values().forEach(List::clear)`

instead of

```
parentsMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.clear())
```

Hashmap is always modified when there is a key->value changed